# Is there a way to newly commit the latest 10 in SVN?

Tags: linux, svn

I have SVN with many tags.

Due to capacity issues, I would like to create a new SVN with just 10 latest tags.

I know manually check out the latest 10 tags and commit them to the newly created SVN.

But isn't there an easier way than this?

Answer (score 2):

Tags are in separate tree in SVN, thus - your way you'll lost all intermediate changes between tags (because they happened in trunk|branch)

More bulletproof and safe way will be "Truncate repository history, starting from 10-th historical tag from HEAD"

In this case you have:

- Find revision on starting point of dump
- Dump repo-range in dump-file with [`svnadmin dump`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.dump.html) (use `svnadmin dump ... -r FROM:HEAD` format)
- Restore dump from the above into the new repo, using `svnadmin load`